# Are there any (functional or nuanced) differences between rebuilding an index and a full drop/create? If so, what are they?

Tags: sql-server, index, fragmentation

I have been working on index fragmentation for indexes that are heavily used and causing performance decreases. Our standard job checks fragmentation levels and reorgs if >5% and <30%, and rebuilds if >30%. As far as I have found these don't seem to be functionally different but I'm being asked if a drop/create is more effective as a client tried this on their own and believes they saw greater improvement. Is this truly possible?

This is comparing a full DROP and CREATE vs ALTER INDEX REBUILD on a non-clustered index.

Comment: These links might answer your question. http://www.kendalvandyke.com/2010/09/index-operations-showdown-drop-create.html https://sqlstudies.com/2014/12/11/drop-index-and-create-index-vs-alter-index-rebuild/

Comment: Do you mean a full DROP and CREATE, or CREATE...WITH DROP_EXISTING?

Comment: A full DROP and CREATE. I apologize for the lack of clarity.

Comment: You can't DROP/CREATE the index as an online operation.  That would be considered a rebuild.

Comment: Obligatory: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/should-i-worry-about-index-fragmentation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Internals, page 366

> You can completely rebuild an index in several ways. You can use a simple combinination of DROP INDEX followed by CREATE INDEX, but this method is probably the least preferable.

But appeals to authority are boring, so let's test it ourselves!

## Performance:

Set up a table with a non-clustered index, load it with junk, and build a table for logging time.

```
CREATE TABLE IndexTest
(ID int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
Junk uniqueidentifier)

CREATE TABLE IndexTestLogging
(Operation char(10),
TimeInms int)
GO

INSERT IndexTest
SELECT TOP 1000000 NEWID() AS Junk
FROM sys.all_objects a
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects c

CREATE INDEX IX_IndexTest ON IndexTest(Junk)
GO
```

Now let's build some procs that will DROP/CREATE or REBUILD, plus log (approximately) the time taken:

```
CREATE PROC usp_DropCreate
AS
DECLARE @t1 datetime,
@t2 datetime

--scramble the table for fragmentation
UPDATE IndexTest
SET Junk = NEWID()

SET @t1 = GETDATE()
DROP INDEX IX_IndexTest ON IndexTest
CREATE INDEX IX_IndexTest ON IndexTest(Junk)
SET @t2 = GETDATE()

INSERT IndexTestLogging
SELECT 'DropCreate' AS Operation, DATEDIFF(millisecond,@t1,@t2) AS TimeInms
GO


CREATE PROC usp_Rebuild
AS
DECLARE @t1 datetime,
@t2 datetime

--scramble the table for fragmentation
UPDATE IndexTest
SET Junk = NEWID()

SET @t1 = GETDATE()
ALTER INDEX IX_IndexTest ON IndexTest REBUILD
SET @t2 = GETDATE()

INSERT IndexTestLogging
SELECT 'Rebuild' AS Operation, DATEDIFF(millisecond,@t1,@t2) AS TimeInms
```

OK, now we can run each procedure multiple times and gather data

```
EXEC usp_DropCreate
GO 10

EXEC usp_Rebuild
GO 10

SELECT AVG(
         CASE 
         WHEN Operation = 'DropCreate' THEN TimeInms
         END) AS AvgDropCreate,
       AVG(
         CASE 
         WHEN Operation = 'Rebuild' THEN TimeInms
         END) AS AvgRebuild
FROM IndexTestLogging
```

Here are my own results: average time in ms for DROP/CREATE: 2547, for REBULD: 1314

It looks like in my contrived example, the winner is REBUILD.

## Constraints

What if the index was created to support a constraint? In this case, a simple DROP and CREATE will fail because you have to drop the constraint first. Let's look at the clustered index from the previous example.

```
--Find out what the clustered index is named - it will be different for you
SELECT name
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('IndexTest')

--enjoy the error message
DROP INDEX PK__IndexTes__3215078707C12930 ON IndexTest
```

Note that the other two methods succeed:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK__IndexTes__3215078707C12930 ON IndexTest(ID)
WITH DROP_EXISTING

ALTER INDEX PK__IndexTes__3215078707C12930 ON IndexTest REBUILD
```

Of course, like Erik alluded to, your actual problems probably have nothing to do with fragmentation, but hey, this was fun.

Comment: I'd also add that drop/create runs a risk of forgetting settings.  Compression for example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other points.

BTW, how do you find

> indexes that are heavily used

?

One of the ways I know is querying `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`. And regarding this system DMV the following should be mentioned:

- when you do `DROP INDEX` and then `CREATE INDEX` (as well as when you
  do `CREATE INDEX ... WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)`) index usage
  statistics resets
- in contrast `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` retains index usage statistics

Regarding the `sys.indexes` DMV (and related):

- when you do `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` the value of `index_id` is
  retained
- the same is true for `CREATE INDEX ... WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)`
- doing `DROP INDEX` and then `CREATE INDEX` can change value of
  `index_id`

(though I'm not sure whether it has some use)